# Difference between SelectionChange and ValueChange events of Kendo-Combobox

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I have just started working on Kendo Controls in Angular. I have found an example [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/combobox/#toc-events) where its making use of both selectionChange and valueChange event. So, my question is what is the difference between these both and when to use them?

Thank you

Answer (score 12):

Imagine focusing the combobox, pressing the down arrow a few times until you find what you want, and hitting enter to choose it. In this example, each press of the down arrow changes the *selection*, and pressing enter changes the *value*.